# SCCM - Disable automatic restart of failed task sequence

Tags: operating-system, sccm-2012

Specifically 2012, but I'll take what I can get:

When a task sequence fails, it automatically starts a 15 minute countdown and then restarts (provided there is no command prompt open). Is there a way to disable this at the task sequence level?

I don't want to set every step to 'continue on error' either. The purpose is so that when one leaves and comes back then they know it failed and at what step, not just pseudo complete, it may as well just auto reboot in that case.

Sample screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extend or prevent the restart time on task sequence failure, use the "**SMSTSErrorDialogTimeout**" task sequence variable. Set this variable to the desired timeout in seconds. Or set it to 0 for a timeout of 1,193,046 days.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, 1 million days is close enough to never for my purposes. Thanks and welcome to server fault.

Answer (score 1):

I have a "lo-fi" solution to let me know if a OSD failed.

After the TS completes the "Setup Windows and ConfigMgr" step I copy a simple .vbs script that prompts each time a user logs on that the deployment failed.

```
xcopy "\\publicshare\OSD_deployment_failed.vbs" "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
```

The contents of the OSD_deployment_failed.vbs is simple message.

```
MsgBox "Setup failed, not all steps in TS finshed" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &_ 
"You need to run the TS again& vbCrLf, vbExclamation,"IT department"
```

The last step in the TS is to clear the .vbs from the startup folder, if the deployment failed any of the previous steps then any user who logs on will get notified.

```
cmd /c del "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\OSD_deployment_failed.vbs" /s
```

Comment: For future work @FannarLevy, check out the accepted answer, it may make things easier for you.